# Direct volumetric plot 3D array

Tags: python, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, mayavi, voxel

I am looking to plot a 3-dimensional array. Is there a method that I can directly feed the array, that plots a voxel and with the actual value (color) at the coordinate that arises from the position in the 3d array?
All methods I have found so far (e.g. ax.voxels, mlab.points3d...) take an array for x,y and z coordinate each, but I would like to not explicitly state the coordinates, just like one doesn't have to do in plt.imshow.

Edit:
I want to plot an array e.g. like this:
a = [ [ [10,20], [5,300] ] , [ [7,80],[9,12] ] ]
This should give a cube at that has the values inside the array at the coordinates that the indices of the array give. I'd like to know if there's a method that can take such an array directly and plot it.

Comment: Your question sounds a bit vague. You should at least give some sample plot you want or some test data. You can use scatter3d with the z values as the color parameter

Comment: You want to plot a big cube consisting of small voxels? So voxels not lying at the edge of the cube are not to be seen? Did you see [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/voxels_numpy_logo.html)?

Comment: @Bazingaa I edited my question, does that help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question seems to be how to plot an (n,m,l)-shaped array as voxels where the color of the voxels is given by the values of the array. This requires a colormap and a normalization to convert the values to colors (because `voxels` do not take colormaps as input directly).

The rest is straight forward:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

a = np.array( [ [ [10,20], [5,300] ] , [ [7,80],[9,12] ] ] )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

cmap = plt.get_cmap("viridis")
norm= plt.Normalize(a.min(), a.max())
ax.voxels(np.ones_like(a), facecolors=cmap(norm(a)), edgecolor="black")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I realize now I thought about the problem in the wrong way. Do you by any chance know how to set the opacity for the voxels? I am trying using alpha, but it doesn't change anything (even though it does take it as an argument).

Comment: If you look at [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/voxels_numpy_logo.html), the alpha is encoded in the facecolors; those are RGBA instead of RGB colors that are being used.